# How to split a file path into its components with CMD-commands and concatenate again with double backslashes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, split, concatenation

I need help with the following problem:

**I want to split a filepath into its components inside the batch-file with CMD-commands.**

First of all I determine the path where the batch file is located:

```
set home=%~dp0  (e.g. C:\SomeFolder\OtherFolder\)
```

What I need is to extract this string into:

- C:
- SomeFolder
- OtherFolder

and re-concatenate these components to:

- C:\\SomeFolder\\OtherFolder\\

This helps me loop thru the elements of the file-path

```
set List=!home!
:ProcessListSource
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=\" %%a IN ("!List!") DO ( 
  if "%%a" NEQ "" ( 
        echo %%a
  )
  if "%%b" NEQ "" (
      set List=%%b
      goto :ProcessListSource
  )
)
```

the loop works fine, the components of the file-path echoed correctly. I thought it will be easy to change the echo statement by simple string concatenation

```
if "%%a" NEQ "" ( 
set foo=%foo%%%a
set foo=%foo%\\
)
```

the result is simply sobering. Only the backslashes will be added to the variable. Where is my mistake? Echoing %%a works fine, but in the concatenate-statement seems to be an error. I played around with quotes and '!' but nothing works.

Any help on that is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to double the backslashes, it's simpler to use a replace.

```
set "home=%~dp0"
set "foo=%home:\=\\%"
echo %foo%
```

Your code could also work:

But the key word is here `EnableDelayedExpansion` (like every day).
That's the cause why `%foo%` doesn't expand as expected.

Add this line after your `@echo off`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and change your concatenation block to

```
if "%%a" NEQ "" ( 
set foo=!foo!%%a
set foo=!foo!\\
)
```

Comment: that works great for me - never thought that it is was so easy

Comment: yes, this was already in there. Forgot to post. The concat correction helps anyway